# Influxdb query gets curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: influxdb

I am running a complex query on Influxdb version 1.4.2.
I can see that the query is running (using show queries). But if the query reaches more than 60 seconds. I get **curl: (52) Empty reply from server** 
I tried to change query-timeout from "0" to "5m"

```
query-timeout = "5m"
```

But it did not change anything. 
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was not with influxdb**. It was my Load balancer. once I checked the curl from the influx machine everything worked just fine.